# DB2 compare date of type numeric to timestamp of type char

Tags: sql, date, timestamp, db2, compare

I am trying to compare the dates of two different tables in DB2. One table has a date formatted as `YYYYMMDD` with `OleDbType.Numeric`. Then the other table has a timestamp to the hundredth thousands with `OleDbType.Char`, 
example: "2015-05-13-10.10.47.000000" <-- but I only need the date in `YYYYMMDD` format.

I tried using `VARCHAR_FORMAT(table2.date, 'YYYYMMDD')` but I get the error:

> SQL0171: Argument 2 of function VARCHAR_FORMAT not valid

and using the `Format` function isn't recognized by DB2.

How can I compare these two columns?

Comment: What DB2 version and platform? Also, you say that the other data type is timestamp in the title, but in the question itself you indicate it's character; which is it really?

Comment: We are using the DB2 that is built into AS400 Z/OS, I am having trouble finding the exact version but I believe it is 4.6.    The timestamp is of type char.

Comment: AS/400 and z/OS are two entirely different things. Unless you can figure out the database version, it's hard to offer a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a code sample that works under DB2 for z/OS V.10.  The char value seems to be in TIMESTAMP26 format so it'll implicitly cast:

```
WITH table AS (
SELECT
 20170428 date_num,
 '2015-05-13-10.10.47.000000' timestamp_str
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 )
SELECT 
  DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(date_num),'YYYYMMDD')),
  DATE(timestamp_str)
FROM table
```